# SQL database model for a scoring system

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala

What would be the best way to accomplish the following: I have access to some player info via an API. I'd now like to persist, in a sql database, the way to calculate scores using the player info. How would one accomplish that?

For example:

I want to compute scores based on RushingYards: Int, Touchdowns: Int and Interceptions: Int. Pretty much, I want to create a scoring system with the following specs:

```
1 point for every 25 RushingYards,
3 points for every Touchdown
2 points for every Interception
```

Writing this in pure code is simple, but how can I put this in the SQL DB, as I need multiple, dynamically created "scoring systems"? Lastly, I would like to retrive the persisted data and use it to compute scores in Scala.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hard to answer definitively without some assumptions, but I'll make those assumptions and try.

I would simply store the data retrieved from the API in the database.  I might not even do this if the API were highly available and I could get the data (again) any time I wanted to.

If the rules are simple and confined to what you've outlined (plus a finite number of additional rules or types of rules), you would simply code the rules into the application logic and have a single table where rule inputs are stored.  For example, the rule input table could look something like:

```
RuleInputs
------------------------ 
RuleInputId 
LeagueId 
NumPointsPer25Yards 
NumPointsPerTouchdown 
NumPointsPerInterception 
NumPointsPerSack
```

This is overly simplified, but you get the idea.

If the rules could change at any time, and the types of rules could also change (e.g. 1 point every time the coach yells at the ref), you are probably looking at more of a business rules engine, which would have to allow flexible fields/metadata and pluggable application logic.

One metadata model is [Entity-Attribute-Value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model).  You could also consider some sort of NoSQL solution for a schema-less model.  I would recommend against using a metadata model unless you absolutely have to.  If you could define all the possible types of rules of front, it will result in a much simpler system.  Building a pluggable rules engine is too much for SO (and is not a small endevour).  I would take a look around to see if some sort of open source system exists.

Comment: Do you know any reading material about what you said in the last paragraph?

Comment: Added some info to the end of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Without any details of your tables, no real answer is possible. But here's one possible way:

```
SELECT 
   SUM(CASE type
       WHEN 'RushingYards' THEN (FLOOR(yards / 25))
       WHEN 'Touchdown' THEN 3
       WHEN 'Interception' THEN 2
   ) AS points
FROM player_actions
GROUP BY ...
```

The queries will flow naturally once you figure out what your table schemas should be.